# find all records where two conditions are true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to find all records where two conditions are true. For example:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p302 > Person.all
 => #<Person name: "Jane", city: "Green Bay", state: "Wisconsin", single: true>
 => #<Person name: "Dick", city: "Madison", state: "Wisconsin", single: false> 
 => #<Person name: "Tom", city: "Milwaukee", state: "Wisconsin", single: true>
```

I want to get the "Jane" and "Tom" records. I'm trying this, but it doesn't work:

```
Person.find_all_by_state("Wisconsin").find_all_by_single(true)
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`Person.where(:state => "Wisconsin", :single => true)`

Comment: For the record, in newer Ruby, you can do `state: "Wisconsin", single: true`, because they changed the Hash literal syntax for those with Symbol keys.

Answer (score 9):

I would go with dmarkow's answer, but as a little bit of additional trivia you can also do this:

```
Person.find_all_by_state_and_single("Wisconsin", true)
```

Chain as many fields using `_and_` as desired. The `where` syntax is much neater than this however.

Comment: It's much neater but this actually works for me. I'm using the Plucky gem and it's not giving the expected output using the where clause.

Comment: user368937: This is the old syntax that was the norm in Rails 2. dmarkow's is for Rails 3.

Answer (score 5):

Example using a OR condition:

```
model_name.where("field_1 = ? OR field_2 = ?", params[:search_string],  params[:search_string])
```